# How can I adjust aspect ratio on Mi TV Box 2 when projecting content from the side of the room?

Tags: android, display, resolution, android-tv, projector

I positioned the projector on the side of my room, and now the pixels appear wider. I am using the Mi TV Box 2, and I unlocked the developer tools in an attempt to adjust the resolution. However, this approach did not yield the desired result since I specifically want to alter the pixel width, not the overall number of pixels.

I attempted to adjust the screen size and density like this
`adb shell wm size 1920x1080`